# How to refresh token for GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, openid, graphserviceclient

I have the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I get `GraphServiceClient` using DI:

```
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    public MailsRangeModel(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }
```

then I try to call

```
await _graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders[folderId].Messages
```

I get the following error when token is expired:

> ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Message: Access
> token has expired or is not yet valid.

I know about ability to change token lifecycle on Active Directory, but I don't have access to it.

I just want to get new token instead of show this exception to client.

How to do it?

Comment: You should send one additional `POST` request for getting `refresh token` you could [`have a look here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token)

Comment: In addition, may we know which `auth protocol` you are using to get access token?

Comment: I don't think that this line "await _graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders[folderId].Messages" will work. It should be something like this "var messages = await _graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders[folderId].Messages.Request().GetAsync();"